# Java pass Object to Quartzjob ( Quartz 2 )

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I use Quartz 2 to create a Interval in Java.

Now i want to pass the **Object obj1** from the *Updater* to the *UpdateJob*.
How can i make this ?

Interval.java/Updater :

```
public class Interval {

    public static void Updater( Object obj1 ) throws SchedulerException {
        JobDetail job = newJob(UpdateJob.class).withIdentity("UpdateJob", "Group1").build();
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("UpdateTrigger", "Group1")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever()).build();
        Scheduler sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        sched.start();
    }

}
```

UpdateJob.java :

```
    public class UpdateJob implements Job {

          public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
                            throws JobExecutionException {

                  //obj1 jobs

          }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datamap

```
job.getJobDataMap().put("key",obj1);
```

and then get it from job:

```
    JobDataMap data = _context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    Object o = data.get("key");
```